# change name of generated folders

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have created an vue.js app and now i want to deploy it. It generates an folder `css`, `js` and an `index.html` file. Is it possible to rename the `css` and `js` to, for example `myAppCss` and `myAppJs`?

I have searched in https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config for an solution but couldnt find anything.

Comment: Could you add your current webpack config?

Comment: That's a good question. It's doable but maybe not straight out of the box.

Comment: @Titulum where do i find it exactly?